# Processing Ajax Data Using External Function Results in Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax function below which returns data. I can log data to the console, but I want to process the "skilllist" in a separate function to generate HTML to add to the overall string. The function returns the HTML, but when it does so it generates an error just because the function is called.

My AJAX function looks like:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/search/projectsearchsimple/",
    data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
            search : $("#id_search").val() },
    success: function(data) {
      //update_messages(data.messages);
      console.log(data);
      $("#resultsarea").show();
      $("#resultspanel").empty();
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      var resultshtml = "";


      for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        var skilllist = [...data[i].skilllist];

        var skillsbox = createSkillsBox(skilllist);
        resultshtml = resultshtml + "<div class='row'><div class='col-2'>" +
                      "<a href='/project/projectpage/" + data[i].id + "'>" +
                        data[i].name + "</a>" + "</div>" + "<div class='col-2'>by " +
                        data[i].owner__username + "</div><div class='col-3'>Created on: " +
                        data[i].created + "</div></div>";
      }
      $("#resultspanel").append(resultshtml);

    }
  });
});
```

The external function looks as:

```
  function createSkillsBox(skills) {
skillsboxhtml = "<div class='menu-outer'><div class='table'><ul id='skills{{ job.id }}' class='horizontal-list skillsboxuser'>";

for(i=0;i<skills.length;i++) {
  skillsboxhtml += "<li><strong>" + skills[i]  + "</strong></li>"
}

skillsboxhtml += "</ul></div></div>";
return skillsboxhtml;
```

}

The error received in the console sates "TypeError: data[i] is undefined[Learn More]". If I comment out the line "var skillsbox = createSkillsBox(skilllist);" it works doesn't error.

The data variable contains:

```
 [{"skilllist": ["Programming", "Musician", "Writing"], "name": "Project KFC", "id": 3, "owner__username": "kyle", "created": "18/11/19 10:00", "description": "description"}]
```

I have tried moving the function to inside the Ajax method and I have tried with passing data[i] direct before i tried the shallow copy.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to declare the variable `i` with `var` or `let` in all of your `for` loops. Currently, they all share the same **global** `i`.

Comment: As above with more info: when your `createSkillsBox` runs, it changes the value of `i` so that when it returns to `resultshtml = resultshtml + `, `i` has changed, likely going beyond `data.length`.  Use `for(var j=0` in your inner loop to confirm, then use `for (var ...` each time.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly that, I added "var" in front of the i variables in the for loops and now it is working. It makes sense about it treating it as if global as you said. Can you write that as the answer and I will accept it.